# How does the Smart card distinguish Case 2 and Case 3 APDU headers form eachother in T0?

Tags: smartcard, javacard, iso-7816-3

I'm trying to understand the way `T0` protocol works in smart cards. Based on the corresponding standard (ISO/IEC 7816/3), the communication in this protocol initiates by sending a 5-byte command header (CLA-INS-P1-P2-P3) from the reader to the card; and after this header, the reader shall wait for a procedure byte from the card. The *prodecure byte* can be one of the following values:

1. `60` => It is NULL(!), the reader shall wait for another `procedure byte`
2. `6X` (!60) or `9X` => The value is SW1, and the reader shall wait for the SW2
3. `INS` or `INS^FF` => It is an ACK. The reader shall send the remaining bytes

Let's assume that the reader send `AA BB CC DD EE` to the card. The question is that *How does the card can find out if the EE value in the received header is for a case 2 (Le), 3(Lc) or 4 (Lc) APDU command?*

And also I can't understand why it is invalid to use `6X` and `9X` for INS values. Actually it makes sense to prevent developer to use `60` for SW1 (Because then the reader can not distinguish SW1 from NULL procedure byte), but it does not make sense to prevent him from using `6X` and `9X` for INS values. Any clue?

I've checked whole the document to find out any information regarding this question, but the more I read the more I get confused. The relation between APDU and TPDU is not distinguishable also.

Comment: Well, I know that there are multiple JavaCard methods that the developer have to call depending on the case of APDU that he used; but my assumption is that the communication component in the card (ISO7816 UART implementation) will send the APDU to the applet once it is completed, not right after receiving the header. Am I wrong? If I am wrong, then maybe the communication component can distinguish these different cases from eachother based on the JCAPI method that developer calls.

Comment: For the status code part see this related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75067315/1435475).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you've already indicated yourself, the T=0 protocol does a terrible job when it comes to separating layers. And the question you've asked shows that this is not just the case between the data link & transport layer, but also between the transport layer and the application layer.

The simple truth is that the card knows which command is being send when looking at the 4 bytes of the header. It simply knows how to interpret P3 by looking at the other values. That's also why you won't find any commands that switch case based on information within P3 or any C_DATA (command data).

In Java Card you can see the following remark for `setIncomingAndReceive`:

> - In T=0 ( Case 3&4 ) protocol, the P3 param is assumed to be Lc.

so the transport buffer simply contains the 5 byte header initially and then you should only retrieve data after you've inspected the header. Of course, the card may have already received other data because of some buffering taking place - especially for T=1 and T=CL, but you should definitely not assume such a thing in advance.

Note that secure messaging (commonly case 4, as you also want to protect the header & status words) is detected using the first CLA byte, so just looking at the INS may not be enough. Similarly the SELECT command has different "ISO cases" that depend on the values of P1/P2. If you define your own APDU's then it is up to you of course.

Comment: *"The simple truth is that the card knows which command is being send when looking at the 4 bytes of the header"* <-- Based on the methods that the developer used in the application, right? So this means that the ISO7816 UART communication component sends the APDU header to the Javacard applet right after receiving it, and then based on the applet behaviour it decides about the `Procedure byte`. Am I understand correctly?

Comment: Well, it is the protocol that defines the APDU's one might hope. If the developer is also the protocol designer, then yes, correct :) Many applications borrow heavily from the commands in ISO 7816-4/9 etc. so and these have been predefined (more or less, 7816-4 is a mess with many commands and secure messaging half-defined).

Comment: Thank you Mr.Bodewes. Any idea about the reason that the standard prohibited `6X/9X` for INS usage?

Comment: Not from the top of my mind unfortunately. As T=1 is a byte oriented protocol it may clash with some other usage. Of course the status words start with those values, so that's a thing, but those are traveling in the other direction. I can take an educated guess they are reserved for (out of band) signaling. I'd have to read ISO 7816-3 to be sure.

Comment: @MyAccount Regarding 6X/9X .. AFAIK they are used in T=0 for simple flow control (similarily to frame wait time extension in T=1 + card can send response one byte at a time. It uses value 0x60 for wait extension + complementary(xor? /xor 6X=9X/) value of INS is used for sending byte-by-byte). It is all defined in 7816-3 so please verify my thoughts.

Comment: @vlp Thanks! I found the reason behind that. As already mentioned in the question, when the reader sends the APDU header to the card, it has to wait for a `procedure byte` from the card; and this procedure byte is one of `60` (for wait request?), `6X or 9X` (as SW), or `INS or INS^FF` (Ask more byte[s]). If the user choose `6X` or `9X` for the INS byte, then when the card returns a `Procedure Byte`, the reader won't be able to distinguish if it is a SW or it is a _Ask more byte[s]_ request.